# Understanding Javascript String.prototype.includes() when dealing with empty string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Could anyone tell me how it prints "got" when the string does not contain empty string at all?

```
const sentence = "Depreciation";

if(sentence.includes("")){
 console.log("got"); 
}
else{
 console.log("none"); 
}
```

[image: Js string.includes()]

I was doing a project where I was supposed to filter a loaded with data array variable content based on the user's input in the search box. Surprisingly, when the user does not input anything (empty string), it returns the original(full) content of the array instead of an empty array. I was using array.filter() and string.includes().

I understood array.filter as it will return a new array which fulfills the condition written inside the filter function, which is the string.includes(). That said, I thought it is supposed to return empty array since the array content itself does not has any element contains empty string.

That leads me to the question asked, any of your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using `.includes`, you should just use `==` in this case, since the only string that will ever match by your logic is the empty string itself. Any other string will not contain an "empty" character. What even *is* an empty character?

Comment: Every string includes an empty string inside it. The same way that the string `"abc"` includes `"a"` - there is a substring with the same length and the same content. Any string has a substring with a length of zero. And the content of that substring is always going to be `""`.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you so much for your effort in explaining to me! It is clearer to me now :)

Comment: @Liftoff Thank you for the advice! I understand your idea, but I was actually on different use-case which I did not show here, and would not be applicable to the use-case. But still thank you!